# Identifying variable type in GNU Octave

Tags: octave

When practicing with Octave I created a variable with the name `my_name = ["Andrew"]` and upon asking Octave to interpret whether it was a string it outputted a '0'. Again when using the `typeinfo(my_name)` I got `ans = string`. Why am I getting this sort of output?

```
octave:47> my_name = ["Andrew"]

my_name = Andrew

octave:48> isstring(my_name)

ans = 0

octave:49> typeinfo(my_name)

ans = string
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://octave.org/doc/v4.4.0/Character-Arrays.html) (emphasis mine):

> isstring (s)
>
> Return true if s is a string array.
>
> A string array is a data type that stores strings (row vectors of characters) at each element in the array. It is distinct from character arrays which are N-dimensional arrays where each element is a single 1x1 character. It is also distinct from cell arrays of strings which store strings at each element, but use cell indexing ‘{}’ to access elements rather than string arrays which use ordinary array indexing ‘()’.
>
> Programming Note: **Octave does not yet implement string arrays so this function will always return false.**

That is, `isstring` will always return `false` (or `0`), no matter what the input is.

You should use `ischar` to determine if the input is a character array (==string).